# multiple condition check in for loop using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to check multiple conditions in for loop using robot framework but it never returns true.

```
:FOR    ${RowIndex} IN RANGE    0   ${rowscount}    
    ${ColumnText1}  Get Text    //*[@id='RadSearchGrid_ctl00__${RowIndex}']/td[3]       
    ${ColumnText2}  Get Text    //*[@id='RadSearchGrid_ctl00__${RowIndex}']/td[4]       
    ${ColumnText3}  Get Text    //*[@id='RadSearchGrid_ctl00__${RowIndex}']/td[5]       
    ${bStatus}  | Run Keywords |    Should Contain |    ${ColumnText1} and ${ColumnText2} and ${ColumnText3}    | ${VoucherNumber} and ${Voucherdate} and ${VoucherAmount}
    Exit For Loop If    ${bStatus}
```

${bStatus} Never returns true.

Comment: I don't think that `Run Keywords`or `Should Contain` return any value. According to the [current doc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Contain) `Should Contain` "fails", if the expected value is not found.

Comment: @Würgspaß I am sorry , it is Run Keyword and Return Status

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
    :FOR    ${RowIndex} IN RANGE    0   ${rowscount}    
        ${ColumnText1}  Get Text    //*[@id='RadSearchGrid_ctl00__${RowIndex}']/td[3]       
        ${ColumnText2}  Get Text    //*[@id='RadSearchGrid_ctl00__${RowIndex}']/td[4]       
        ${ColumnText3}  Get Text    //*[@id='RadSearchGrid_ctl00__${RowIndex}']/td[5]       

       ${bStatus}=   Run Keyword And Return Status   Run Keywords   Should Contain   ${ColumnText1}   ${VoucherNumber}   AND  Should Contain    ${ColumnText2}   ${Voucherdate}   AND   Should Contain    ${ColumnText3}   ${VoucherAmount}

        Exit For Loop If    ${bStatus}
```

Comment: It gives error : Keyword 'BuiltIn.Should Contain' expected 2 to 4 arguments, got 9.

Comment: Edited the Answer , please use    

`${bStatus}=   Run Keyword And Return Status   Run Keywords   Should Contain   ${ColumnText1}   ${VoucherNumber}   AND  Should Contain    ${ColumnText2}   ${Voucherdate}   AND   Should Contain    ${ColumnText3}   ${VoucherAmount}`